# Close notifications for default messaging app when secondary messaging app views message

Tags: java, android

I have created a SMS app that is created to be a backup to your default messaging app. It presents the user with a notification when a message is received so it can be used in only certain situations that the user finds fit. It is meant to be a secondary messaging app so it should not be set as the default.

Is there a way to implement the following functionality?

If the user receives a message and opens the message in my messaging app, the app should then lookup what the default messaging app is and cancel the notification so that the user does not have to go and close that additional notification after already responding to the message they received.

**10/12/17**

I have found that I can get the package for the default SMS app like this:

```
Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);
```

Is there a way to cancel notifications when providing a given package?

**10/14/17**

I am now using a NotificationListener service that receives all posted notifications. The issue I am seeing now is that when I get the specific notification I want to cancel, and I call cancel on the NotificationManager for it, it does not cancel.

```
notificationManager.cancel(sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId());
```

I have also even tried to cancel all of the active notifications, like below, and it closes all notifications except for the one for the default sms app. Is there a known reason for this?

```
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

**10/15/17**

Here is my onNotificationPosted() function:

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)
{
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (DefaultSMSPackage == null)
        DefaultSMSPackage = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(getApplicationContext());

    if (sbn.getPackageName().equals(DefaultSMSPackage))
        nManager.cancel(sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId());
}
```

Comment: You could implement a `NotificationListenerService` and do it from there, but the user would have to manually enable your app as a listener in the device Settings.

Comment: @MikeM. I was looking into using a NotificationListenerService but I did not realize that the user would have to manually enable the app as a listener. Is this in the android developer documentation? I do not see it.

Comment: I don't think so. I just wrote one the other day, after not having done so for a while, and I couldn't remember where that darn setting was exactly, so my first check was the docs, but I never found anything there.

Comment: @MikeM. Please see my latest edit.

Comment: Hunh, that's a bummer. AFAIK, there's nothing special about the default app's Notifications, though maybe something changed recently. I have no problem dismissing it on my device. Which Android version are you testing on? What are you using for your default app?

Comment: @MikeM. I'm on version 7.0. The default app I have set now is Google's Android Messages app.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you might not be able to cancel ongoing `Notification`s from a `NotificationListenerService`, so if that's how that app is setting it, you might be out of luck.

Comment: I should've mentioned that `StatusBarNotification` has the `isOngoing()` method, so you can check if that's the issue with those `Notification`s.

Comment: @MikeM. I checked and isOngoing() returns false for the default sms application. This is very interesting. I have edited my post with my onNotificationPosted() function just in case I am doing something odd that I don't notice.

Comment: You don't call `cancel()` on `NotificationManager`. You call one of the `cancelNotification()` methods in [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html).

Comment: @MikeM. Well...I missed that lol. That works now. Awesome. If you want to put an answer in I'll accept it.

Comment: Ah, cool. I hadn't considered that, but easy fix, eh? I'll put together an answer when I get to my desk here a little later. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Posted. Btw, I have to apologize for not noticing that yesterday's edit was clearly using `NotificationManager`. I should've paid closer attention. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html), your app can track and dismiss `Notification`s posted from other apps. Implementing an `onNotificationPosted()` method will allow your app to get the `Notification`s as they're posted, and the `getActiveNotifications()` methods will let you access the visible `Notification`s at any other point during your `Service`'s lifetime.

When you wish to dismiss a `Notification`, you will call one of `NotificationListenerService`'s `cancelNotification()` methods. If you're supporting Android versions before 21, make sure to use the appropriate overload for the version. Prior to 21, you need to use [`cancelNotification(String pkg, String tag, int id)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#cancelNotification(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int)). From 21 on, [`cancelNotification(String key)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#cancelNotification(java.lang.String)) is the one to use, and the other will not work if your `targetSdkVersion` is 21+.

To activate your `NotificationListenerService`, the user must manually enable it in the device Settings. The exact location for that setting varies with the Android version, and likely with certain manufacturers, so it would be helpful if your app could open that page for the user. [`Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS) is an `Intent` action that you can use with `startActivity()` to do just that. As the documentation notes:

> In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this.

You can do this by checking that `resolveActivity()` called on the `Intent` does not return null, or possibly by catching the `ActivityNotFoundException` that `startActivity()` might throw.